# How to fetch posts order by meta value?

Tags: php, wordpress

Well I am stuck in a sorting posts in wordpress! I know this is a previously asked question, but no luck for me the codes and solutions I found here!
The below is code snippet I am using.

```
$args = array(
      'showposts'=>10,
      's' => $search,
      'meta_key'        => 'neighboorhood',
      'meta_value'  => $location,
      'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
      'meta_key'  => 'is_sort',
    );
```

Comment: This question is too broad right now. Please post what you have tried, what happened, and what didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

That can not work, since you use meta_key twice in your array. You should use an meta_query for the where clause, and meta_key only for the sort.

```
$args = array(
    'showposts'=>10,
    's' => $search,
    'meta_query' => array(

        array(
            'key' => 'neighboorhood',
            'value' => $location
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'  => 'is_sort',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num'
);
```

Comment: Hi Niels, This is not working for me. This excludes the wp_posts table from the query. The query being generated is : SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM mlc_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (1802,1804,1985) ORDER BY meta_id ASC

Comment: This is the way to go. If you throw there arguments in a get_posts or a WP_Query function it will 100% work. If you're not changing the query any other way that is.

Answer (score 2):

Just use below mentioned code to fetch posts order by meta_value :

```
<?php 

        $myargs = array(
           'posts_per_page' => 4, //number of post to show
           's' => $search,
           'meta_key' => 'is_sort', //name of meta field
           'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
           'order' => 'ASC', // you can modify it as per your use
           'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'neighboorhood',
                    'value'     => $location,
                    )
                )
        );

        query_posts($myargs );

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

         <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
         <p><?php the_content();?></p>

         <?php endwhile; 
           endif; 
           wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Just use the above mentioned code, you will get your desired result. If you are using this process in case of date field, then please check here for better understanding : http://www.wptricks24.com/how-to-order-wordpress-post-by-custom-field-date

Comment: Thanks Sunil for the answer, anyway I figured it out!