# Order archive posts by number of social shares

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I have Yoast Seo plugin installed into my website and this brings back the number of social shares per post and stores it in the database.

Is it possible to change the archive page to order the posts by the number of social shares?

I've tried a few things listed here but can't seem to get it to work

```
<?php
/* The loop */
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   include( locate_template( 'content-' . $layout_this . '.php' ) );
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one might be tougher than you think. Yoast SEO does not actually store the number of times any given social media outlet is actually shared. This is done by constantly running a check from the respective social media API and will retrieve the number of shares/likes which happened on that respective post.

Essentially what needs to be done is you'd need to hook onto the API a similar way Yoast is doing so, and then start comparing the values which are being sent back from the API in order to order your posts on the front-end by a number of most shares.

The idea for the functionality is pretty useful... I'm hoping that in the future there will be a new table added perhaps with the Yoast plugin which will actually save this data rather than having to refer to the API.

**EDIT:** In theory, this should be possible then if you know what meta value(s) you're working with from the database. As long as the posts have association with these values, this should be possible. You can query posts with specific meta keys and order them, too. Here's an example of what might work within your template, with some adjustments.

```
$args= query_posts(
    array(  'post_type' => 'your post type', //for posts, enter 'post'
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'some_key', //the meta key
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value', //or 'meta_value_num'
    )
);
```

See here as well, someone asked a very similar question : [How to fetch posts order by meta value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966741/how-to-fetch-posts-order-by-meta-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Sorry I got my original post wrong! It's not yeost but another plugin that is storing the social shares count. It's in the "postmeta" table with the meta key of "_totes". I'm sure it is easy to order desc using this but not sure the best way!

Comment: I see, well since you know the meta key you can query your posts and order them by that key. See above for an example, I've edited the answer.